# Hide WooCommerce billing and shipping fields in WordPress user profile

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, field

I can't find an easy way to hide some WooCommerce billing and shipping fields that are visible in the user profile in the backend of WordPress.

For instance I want to hide `billing_address_2` and `shipping_address_2` in the WordPress user profile. Is there a good way to do that with a code snippet? I tried hiding the sixt row in css with the code below, but I can't get that to work either.

```
#fieldset-billing.form-table tr:nth-child(6) {
     display: none;
}
```

How can I hide WooCommerce billing and shipping fields in WordPress user profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide billing and shipping address2 fields from WordPress Backend User profile try this:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_user_styles');
function custom_admin_user_styles() {
    ?>
    <style>
        table#fieldset-billing tr:nth-child(5),
        table#fieldset-shipping tr:nth-child(6){
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>';
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: What happens though if the 5th or 6th child isn't one of those fields?  A new one is added or another is taken away and the 5th and 6th child will be different fields.

Comment: @JoshChristensen You can check yourself and change the right one for each of them if needed… But this is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you Josh and Loic for both your help. I understand that hiding the rows isn't the most sustainable solution, but I simply couldn't get the remove function to work for the WP profile page. Perhaps another plugin is causing an issue there..

Answer (score 7):

The billing and shipping fields displayed in user profile screen are filtered through the hook `woocommerce_customer_meta_fields`.

To remove shipping fields, you can write:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'xbs_remove_shipping_fields' );
function xbs_remove_shipping_fields( $show_fields ) {
    unset( $show_fields['shipping'] );
    return $show_fields;
}
```

To remove all fields, you can return an empty `array`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the snippet and it is working for 'shipping' or 'billing', but when I try 'billing_state' it isn't working.. any idea?

Comment: The `show_fields` array has 2 keys: `billing` and `shipping` each containing an array with `title` and `fields` keys. If you want to hide only `billing_state`, you have to unset `['billing']['fields']['billing_state']` key.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it in the `functions.php` file and just unset them so they don't get registered.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['billing_address_2']);     
     unset($fields['order']['shipping_address_2']);

     return $fields;
}
```

Remove from Account page:

```
function custom_remove_checkout_fields($fields) {
    unset($fields['order']['billing_address_2']);     
    unset($fields['order']['shipping_address_2']);
    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_remove_checkout_fields' );
```

If it shows up in another place you can just add another hook but call

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'new_function_name' );
```

Other hooks they have available you can see in the file `class-wc-countries.php`

for more information and other options you can visit: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: Thank you, but they are still visible on the WordPress user profile page in the backend..

Comment: I've updated the original answer to show how to remove the account page as well.

Comment: @Sjors can you mark which one is the answer and helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', '__return_empty_array' );
```

Add the above line of code to your theme's functions.php file. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS to hide it. .class or #ID

```
.class{
    display: none!important
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way if you might ask.

Answer (score -1):

To hide the WooCommerce billing and shipping fields in the WordPress user profile, you can use the woocommerce_customer_meta_fields filter hook[0]. Here's an example of how you can modify the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'hide_some_fields' );

function hide_some_fields( $show_fields ) {
    unset( $show_fields['billing']['fields']['billing_city'] );
    unset( $show_fields['billing']['fields']['billing_postcode'] );
    unset( $show_fields['billing']['fields']['billing_address_2'] );
    unset( $show_fields['billing']['fields']['billing_company'] );
    unset( $show_fields['shipping']['fields']['shipping_city'] );
    unset( $show_fields['shipping']['fields']['shipping_postcode'] );
    unset( $show_fields['shipping']['fields']['shipping_address_2'] );
    unset( $show_fields['shipping']['fields']['shipping_company'] );

    return $show_fields;
}
```

This code removes the specified billing and shipping fields from the user profile. You can customize the fields to hide by modifying the unset() statements.

Alternatively, if you want to remove all billing and shipping fields, you can return an empty array:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'hide_all_fields' );

function hide_all_fields( $show_fields ) {
    return array();
}
```

This will hide all billing and shipping fields from the user profile.

Please note that this code should be added to the functions.php file of your active theme or a custom plugin file.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.